# Diagnosing a device and browser specific bug - touch event - passive - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, three.js, safari

I have a behaviour in my project that I can only replicate on specific devices/browser.

The correct behaviour is: Device Orientation Controls (Three.js) for the user to "look around" and [this virtual joystick library](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/virtualjoystick.js/examples/basic.html) for users to "move around". It's simple enough and works on most devices:

https://vimeo.com/435063207 - This is it running in Chrome on an iPhone 7

THE BUG: So if you look at this second video (https://vimeo.com/435063178), when I start moving and the joystick appears, the Device Orientation Camera freezes until I let go. It then snaps  into place. Half way through the video, I 'long press' before I start moving and this stops the freezing from happening. (hopefully it's visible)

This behaviour appears when using Safari and also specifically when using Chrome on an iPhone 11. Using Chrome on an iPhone 7 or X doesn't present the same behaviour. (All using the same version of Chrome 83.0.4103.88)

I noticed that if I visit the [official Device Orientation Controls example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=device#misc_controls_deviceorientation) on an iPhone 7 using Safari, I am able to 'move' the body of the site around, which also has the side effect of freezing the camera.

virtualjoystick.js uses preventdefault throughout- I have been reading about changes to prevent default that require us to state passive: false to event listeners. I'm wondering if this can be the same thing causing my freezes. But after trying something like this in the virtualjoystick.js touch event listeners:

```
var __bind  = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
this._$onTouchStart = __bind(this._onTouchStart , this);
this._$onTouchEnd   = __bind(this._onTouchEnd   , this);
this._$onTouchMove  = __bind(this._onTouchMove  , this);
this._container.addEventListener( 'touchstart'  , this._$onTouchStart   , false, { capture: false, passive: false } );
this._container.addEventListener( 'touchend'    , this._$onTouchEnd , false );
this._container.addEventListener( 'touchmove'   , this._$onTouchMove    , false, { capture: false, passive: false } );
if( this._mouseSupport ){
    this._$onMouseDown  = __bind(this._onMouseDown  , this);
    this._$onMouseUp    = __bind(this._onMouseUp    , this);
    this._$onMouseMove  = __bind(this._onMouseMove  , this);
    this._container.addEventListener( 'mousedown'   , this._$onMouseDown    , false, { capture: false, passive: false } );
    this._container.addEventListener( 'mouseup' , this._$onMouseUp  , false, { capture: false, passive: false } );
    this._container.addEventListener( 'mousemove'   , this._$onMouseMove    , false, { capture: false, passive: false } );
}
```

The freezing still happens and it wasn't the quick fix I was hoping. This section of code also gets called out in `virtualjoystick.js:255 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive`.

The part of my animate() function that references the joystick inputs looks like this:

```
 if( joystick.right() ){
        console.log ('move camera right')
        let speed = 50; // px per second
        let movement = speed * deltaTime;
        moveRight (movement);
    }

    if( joystick.left() ){
        console.log ('move camera left')
        let speed = 50; // px per second
        let movement = speed * deltaTime;
        moveRight(-movement);
    }

    if( joystick.up() ){
        console.log ('move camera forward')
        let speed = 50; // px per second
        let movement = speed * deltaTime;
        moveForward( movement);
    }

    if( joystick.down() ){
        console.log ('move camera back')
        let speed = 50; // px per second
        let movement = speed * deltaTime;
        moveForward ( -movement);
    }

    if ( camera.position.y < 10 ) {
        console.log ('Keep Camera Above 10')
        velocity.y = 0;
        camera.position.y = 10;
        canJump = true;
    }
```

If anyone has any thought/ideas that might push me in the right direction it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to add `touch-action: none;` ass a CSS rule to my apps body. Simple!